# Temporarily have no gutters, what do I need to worry about?

Tags: leak, waterproofing, gutters

My gutter contractor has been interrupted by the rain. I will be without gutters for a few days and there is a total of 1.5" of rain predicted over those few days.

I am monitoring my basement for water. It has a known minor leak that pops up during major rainstorms and it has appeared now. Nothing to worry about.

What else should I monitor while my house is without gutters? Leaks? Drainage issues? Protect plants?

Comment: Do you know if you have french drains along the base of your foundation?

Comment: @HandyMan - Not a clue. House built in 1970.

Comment: Water splash, especially in red clay soil leaves unsightly splatters up the wall that can stain badly enough that you need to repaint.

Answer (score 2):

The biggest concern is definitely leakage and drainage issues. It's hard to say without seeing the property. These may be more or less of a concern depending on the grading around your foundation and your soil type.. not to mention other factors such as the type and condition of that foundation, if you have a sump pump or other drainage system, etc.

The plants are probably a minor concern, but a hard drip of rain around my house (which does NOT have gutters) causes there to be a break in the vegetation right at the drip line.

Ultimately, I think you are right to be concerned. If you normally have gutters and even then see water intrusion during heavy storms...well I'd say 1.5" over a few days is moderately heavy!

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to retain some of the water with a few strategically-placed trash barrels to collect runoff. Particularly if you have a valley in your roof, you could probably divert a sizable amount of water. If you want to go crazy you could set up some sloped 2x4s along the drip line to catch more water (although you will probably have to wait until it's raining to set them up).